# AWS Parameter Store : AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException: Rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-parameter-store

At the moment, I need to retrieve the last 10 values of some parameters in AWS Parameters Store

I am using the following code in kotlin :

```
    val p1 = retrieveAllValidVersions("P1")
    val p2 = retrieveAllValidVersions("P2")
    val p3 = retrieveAllValidVersions("P3")
```

Here is the code of the retrieveAllValidVersions

```
    private fun retrieveAllValidVersions(paramName: String): List<ParameterHistory> {
        val res = mutableListOf<ParameterHistory>()
        val ssmClient = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient()
        var nextToken : String? = null
        do {
            val ssmParams = ssmClient.getParameterHistory(GetParameterHistoryRequest()
                    .withName(paramName)
                    .withWithDecryption(true)
                    .withNextToken(nextToken)
            )
            res.addAll(ssmParams.parameters)
            nextToken = ssmParams.nextToken
        } while (nextToken != null)


        return validVersions.sortedByDescending { it.version }.take(10)
    }
```

As described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ssm, the maximum number of versions for a parameter is 100

And as described by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameterHistory.html, you can only retrieve 50 values in maxResults so I need to make 2 calls for each parameter (because I have more than 50 versions)

So each retrieval of my 3 parameters costs 6 queries to SSM

I cache the last 10 values of each param in memory for 5 minutes

The problem is that when multiple instances of my lambdas expire their cache at the same time, they do the retrieval at the same time and

```
com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException: Rate exceeded (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ThrottlingException; Request ID: xxx)
```

For ex, if 3 instances are concerned, that will do 18 requests in less than a second and I will hit the error (note : I do not know exactly if the number of instances that hit this code at the same time is 3, this is just a guess to illustrate that at some point you hit the error)

So I have 2 questions :

**First, is there a way to retrieve last versions of a parameter first ?**

That way, I will then do half of the requests so I will hit the problem less often !

**Second, how do I automatically retry a throttling error ?**

I have find this AWS blog [1] post saying that I have to parse the error message but this is an old post (2013) and this is very ugly (the moment AWS changes the message, all the mechanism collapses) !

[1] : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-handle-a-throttling-maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-error/

A final note : I am using the parameters store with "auto-encryption" and IAM, I do not want to store the parameters in my own database nor to cache them in a shared memory cache like redis !

Comment: It would appear that you are using SSM like a database and they don't want it used that way. You should consider another way of storing such information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein As said in my final note, I already considered implementing my own mechanism but the integration with IAM roles and encryption (i.e KMS) will be such a nightmare ! 
BTW, storing secrets is advertised as a SSM feature (the requirement to retrieve multiple versions comes from the fact that a user can use an old secret for a small amount of time, not just the last one)

Comment: You can catch ThrottlingException, wait for a few seconds and retry by calling the same function for x number of reattempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution / workaround that I will share here.

Please feel free to comment if you find a better way !

TL;DR : the workaround works because it does only 1 request to SSM (per lambda) instead of 6 thanks to GetParametersByPath recursive instead of GetParameterHistory.

So, to simplify, my use case was to store a secret to crypt a token and to be able to use it for 10 hours.

Note : IRL, I use 3 different secrets, hence the P1, P2, P3 in the question. In the following, I will simplify and only talk about 1 secret as it works similarly for any number of secrets (until you reach the maximum number of parameters in SSM which is 10K ...)

It previously works like this : I rotate the secret every hour, I decrypt the token against the last 10 versions -> if a user sends a token that is 11 hours old or more, I cannot decrypt it anymore.

Now, instead of having a single parameter with multiple versions, I have multiple parameters with only the last version of each being safe to use.

My SSM Parameter Store previously looked like (for each parameter)

```
/secret/P1
```

And now it looks like

```
/secrets/P1/s1 -> a secret
/secrets/P1/s2 -> a secret
...
/secrets/P1/s10 -> a secret
/secrets/P1/current -> s4
```

My code now does GetParametersByPath("/secrets") with recursive to retrieve in one request all the valid secrets for all parameters (i.e P1, P2, P3).

**So each lambda does one request, there is little chance to hit RateExceeded.**

When a client sends a token, I try to decrypt against the 10 current secrets.

The secret rotation has changed to : retrieve /current and change the next one (i.e if current is s4, we change s5 and set /current to s5)

As a final note, I also implemented an improvement which is to add /current into the token (unencrypted).

Doing that, I do not need to check against the 10 secrets, only against the one contained in the token.

Note that I could have done that improvement before (by sending the version number unencrypted in the token), I just did not think of it before.

Hope that helps someone

Comment: The use case does seem so oddly contrived, and contrary to the expected use pattern of SSM ... I would expect there must be a simpler way using DynamoDb or some other AWS facility.

Comment: `GetParametersByPath` looks like what I needed!